# Undefined Symbols For Architecture x86

Tags: c++, static

I am coding in c++ and I am attempting to learn about static variables.
When I wrote my practice code, I got this error message:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "pizza::firstLetterFavPizza", referenced from:
>          pizza::favPizzaFirstLetterChan(char) in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Please help! I don't know what's wrong. The source code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
class pizza
{
 public: 
    static char firstLetterFavPizza;

    char favPizzaFirstLetterChan (char letter = firstLetterFavPizza)
    {
     pizza::firstLetterFavPizza = letter;
     return pizza::firstLetterFavPizza;
    }
};

int main()
{
    pizza *a = new pizza();
    pizza *b = new pizza();
    std::cout << a->favPizzaFirstLetterChan('c') << std::endl;
    delete a;
    std::cout << b->favPizzaFirstLetterChan('b') << std::endl;
    delete b;
    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared static data member, but not defined it. Add a definition to your code somewhere (in the global namespace):

```
char pizza::firstLetterFavPizza;
```